# Modal Logic: Equivalence between two formulas

Tags: logic, modal-logic

I want to know if these two modal formulas are equivalent: $\forall x (B(x) \to \diamond (B(x) \land \lnot x))$ $\equiv$ $\forall x (B(x) \to \diamond \lnot x)$.

The -> direction holds and I have a proof. But what about the <- direction? Can someone give a proof or tell why it does not hold?

Just for the context: Both formulas want to express philosophical skepticism. The first formula reads something like: for all propostions x it holds that if you believe in x then it is possible that you believe in x but x is false, the second formula says: for all propositions x it holds that if you believe in x then it is possible that x is false.

Comment: Is this modal third-order logic where the quantifiers range over all propositions? Or is it modal first-order logic? If it's first-order logic, then $\neg x$ doesn't "type-check".

Comment: The first one I guess. Usually in philosophy they want to talk about all propositions whatsoever. But what would be (syntactically) wrong with ~x if it was modal first order logic?

Comment: In first-order logic, you can't quantify over propositions. So the fact that $x$ is quantified over means $x$ does not represent a proposition, which means that $\neg x$ is syntactically nonsense.

Comment: Ah yeah right, then this is a higher order modal logic where you can quantify over all propositions.

Comment: It only makes sense to talk about equivalence *relative to* some "base theory" (e.g. $K$, $S_4$, or similar in the "vanilla" propositional modal setting) or some fixed semantics (e.g. the class of all Kripke frames, or etc.). Especially given the complicated nature of this system per your most recent comment, you need to clarify what that background context is before this question can be answered.

Answer (score 0):

There are two versions of this. In both versions, the two are not logically equivalent.

Version 1: we're in modal first-order logic. There are two predicates: $B(x)$ and $T(x)$, where $T(x)$ informally means "$x$ is true" and $B(x)$ informally means "I believe $x$". The statements are $\forall x , B(x) \to \diamond (B(x) \land \neg T(x))$ and $\forall x , B(x) \to \diamond \neg T(x)$.

In this version, there is no equivalence between the two. To prove this, consider a scenario where there is only one $x$ being quantified over and there are two possible worlds. In possible world $A$, both $B(x)$ and $T(x)$ hold, while in possible world $B$, both $B(x)$ and $T(x)$ do not hold.

So in possible world $A$, we see that $\forall x, B(x) \to \diamond(B(x) \land \neg T(x))$ fails. By contrast, $\forall x, B(x) \to \diamond \neg T(x)$ holds in all possible worlds.

So the two are not equivalent.

Version 2: we're some version of higher-order modal logic, and $x$ is actually a proposition variable.

Define $B(x) = x \land \diamond \neg x$. We see that $B(x) \to \diamond \neg x$ is a tautology, and thus $\forall x, B(x) \to \diamond \neg x$ is a tautology.

We also see that $B(x) \land \neg x$ is always false by definition. That is, $\neg \diamond (B(x) \land \neg x)$.

However, suppose we have some proposition $P$ which holds in possible world $A$ but does not hold in possible world $B$.

Then $\diamond \neg P$ holds. So in possible world $A$, we have $P \land \diamond \neg P$; that is, we have $B(P)$. But we've already show that $\neg \diamond (B(P) \land \neg P)$.

Thus, the statement $\forall x, B(x) \to \diamond (B(x) \land \neg x))$ does not hold in possible world $A$.

So again, the two statements are not equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt to prove the equivalence $\forall x (B(x) \to \diamond (B(x) \land \lnot x))$ $\equiv$ $\forall x (B(x) \to \diamond \lnot x)$.

Again, I just prove <- direction since the other way around got proved already.

So let's assume $\forall x (B(x) \to \diamond \lnot x)$ to be true. Then we have 3 possible cases:

1. $B(x)$,$\diamond \lnot x$
2. $\lnot B(x)$, $\diamond \lnot x$
3. $\lnot B(x)$, $\square x$

In cases 2 and 3 both upper formulas are trivially true, so case 1 is crucial. In case 1 we'd have a (possible) world w with $\lnot x$. Since B(x) ought to be true as well we can always assume another possible world w‘: w $\cup$ B(x), so it's true that  $\diamond (B(x) \land \lnot x)$. But now also $\forall x (B(x) \to \diamond (B(x) \land \lnot x))$ becomes true by verum ex quodlibet.

So whenever $\forall x (B(x) \to \diamond \lnot x)$ is true, so is $\forall x (B(x) \to \diamond (B(x) \land \lnot x))$ which means nothing less than $(\forall x (B(x) \to \diamond \lnot x)) \to (\forall x (B(x) \to \diamond (B(x) \land \lnot x)))$.

Opinions?

Comment: Per my comment, what "background theory" or semantics are you assuming? Without such a thing, this is meaningless.

Comment: @noah: Let‘s say S5 since that is the most common and intuitive, right?

Comment: That's not universal (personally I find $\mathsf{K}$ much more intuitive), but more to the point that's not a sufficient framework for this question: $\mathsf{S5}$ is a *propositional* modal logic, and you need to provide a "background setting" of the more enriched type that you're considering.

Comment: My understanding of modal logic is too weak for that to answer. But in the dissertation where the -> direction is proved one cannot find any remark. It is as if this does not seem to be a problem in modal logic. This is why I thought that the <- direction is just a simple question of yes or no. I have written the author, maybe he can help.

Comment: Can you give a link to the dissertation? That would help immensely.

Comment: Yes, that email still works.

Comment: Got the email out.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're using a proprietary variant of [doxastic logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doxastic_logic) where you can quantify over propositions and further mixing with $\diamond, \square$. But your proof is invalid under the most general normal system K regarding your above "In case 1 we'd have a (possible) world with  $\lnot x$ and $B(x)$". You can only have a possible world with  $\lnot x$, but cannot derive you also have $B(x)$ in the same possible world. Just imagine if your current world $w$ is non-reflexive, and at all accessible worlds you don't believe $x$ (except at current world $w$), then obviously you cannot derive the  left-hand side conjunction starting with $\diamond$...

Comment: From the truth of my antecedens I can deduce a possible world w in which ~x. Since also B(x) is true, I can assume a possible world w‘: w $\cup$ B(x). This is how I get to $\diamond(B(x) \land \lnot x)$. I will add this to my proof. Is it still a problem then?

Comment: @Pippen under rules of $K$ your concerned direction still isn't water tight. Yes you can assume a possible world $w$ at which you have $¬x$, but the tricky part is you cannot be *sure* at such a *generic* assumed world $B(x)$ must hold *simultaneously*. But your other direction is fine. Of course if your system is like S4/S5 which is reflexive, then it's easily seen both direction work.

Comment: Hi mohottnad. I think my system is S5 since it is the most natural and flexible, right? Philosophers almost always talk modalities within S5. That must have a reason. Do I understand you right: In S5 the equivalence would hold?

Comment: @Pippen yes you're right if it's S4/S5 then your concerned direction is fine and equivalence would hold. K just assumes much less and may be more applicable...

Comment: Do you have any idea why in philosophy S5 is almost exclusively used? What has S5 that it has basically become the ZFC of modal logic, esp. in philosophy?

Comment: @Pippen K only lets you open one accessible possible world at a time during semantic valuation containing modal operators. S5 adds reflexivity and Euclidean properties to its frames. Hence if the accessibility relation R is reflexive and Euclidean, R is provably symmetric and transitive as well. Hence for models of S5, R is an equivalence relation, because R is reflexive, symmetric and transitive which means every world can see any other accessible worlds which is naturally what we think of PW semantics and can get more valuations in any already opened worlds thus can get more results...